# How to use Skia on Windows or Linux

Tags: c++, windows, graphics, skia

I have built Skia. What do I do now to get an SkCanvas and draw on it? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897320/skia-rendering-on-windowsskcanvas-from-hdc) answer  does not properly answer the question because
A: It uses API that doesn't exist anymore, like `bitmap.lockPixels()`,
B: It uses some unkown context and draws a `this` from it,
C: It doesn't actually create an SkCanvas?...
Ideally I would like an example that doesn't assume *anything*. A full C++ program that draws *something* on the screen using Skia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow [this detailed procedure](https://gist.github.com/ad8e/dd150b775ae6aa4d5cf1a092e4713add#gistcomment-3059492) (for Linux too!).
If you have problems doing that, in the comments I have proposed solutions for problems I have encountered.